# How to put a custom cell into another custom cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Now I have a PostsController, which is a TableViewController. It contains PostCell. At some point, I want to put another PostCell into one PostCell. What I mean is inside this PostCell, there is also a PostCell. How should I do this with codes in Swift?

Comment: Why are you trying to put a cell in another cell?

Comment: Because I want to show reposts when one person reposts another post.

Comment: You don't put a cell in another cell. Show the cell as another row or write your PostCell class to show additional data if needed. But don't attempt to nest cells.

Comment: I believe technically, you can't. UITableViewCells are a part of a UITableView. I'd hesitate to nest a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell even. If you dig into how a table view works, it reuses it's cells to handle memory efficiently. How do you propose executing `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`? How can you "shape" the table view's data source?

Comment: This would go against the iOS performance guidelines and likely be rejected by apple. Could you post a screenshot of the designs you're attempting to achieve as there may be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Having a cell contain another cell is a non starter. Even if you could hack it together, there would be a large risk of unexpected behaviors.

With that said, there are a few options which I would look into.

1. If possible, go from a single section multiple row layout into multiple section single row layout. When you need to have reposts, they can be additional rows in the section of the original post.

   For example, post 1 is index path (0, 0), post 2 is index path (1, 0), repost of post 2 is index path (1, 1), post 3 is index path (2, 0)…

   It will lock you into the section layout, but you won't have to change `PostCell`.
2. Turn `PostCell` into `PostView` by subclassing `UIView` instead `UITableViewCell`. Have a view container cell that can hold 1 or more instances of `PostView`. This should be a quick way of getting what you asked for, and still give you some flexibility in the layout
3. Turn `PostCell` into `PostViewController`. Have a view controller container cell that can hold your post view controller. This is a little harder, but gives you the most flexibility in how you create your layout.

Comment: Yes, this is an AB problem. The answer is "Don't do that." Well done explaining why and offering other alternatives. (Voted.)